# Connect to MsSQL db from Linux

Tags: php, sql, linux, apache

Does anyone know how I can install an Ms SQL extension 2005 on a Linux webserver? The webserver currently has FreeTDS library version, I have no idea on what that means. But when I try to connect it doesn't say

```
mssql_connect() does not exist
```

But it says

```
Unable to connect to server: xx.xx.xx.xx
```

I am supposing that this is because of the version of the extension since I have occured this problem on windows with `ntwdblib.dll`. But I don't know how to fix this on Linux.

I only need to use the functions. The database is on a windows server so I want to connect to it using `mssql_connect()`.

The webserver is not my own it's a hosting company where I happen to know the hoster so I cannot ask him if he could install windows instead or anything. So could someone tell me how it could work for linux?

I tested it with my own pc and I can connect to the windows server from my pc. But from the webserver it doesnt, it says:

```
unable to connect to the server: "ip"
```

Comment: Are you sure that `ip` is reachable from the linux box? Did you try a ping or telnet connect?

Comment: Yes I connected with my own pc to it and it works without any problem at all

Comment: I wasn't asking about your own PC. I was asking about the Linux webserver.

Comment: Oh yes I checked and it gives no response. The linux server does not receive anything when sending a ping to the windows server

Comment: I tried pinging it from a windows pc. With the windows pc I do receive response without packet loss. However on the linux server nothing

Comment: So you found your problem. Make sure the linux box can connect to the windows server. It doesn't look like a problem with MS SQL but rather like a general connectivity problem.

Comment: @One question: Does the IP of the Windows server start with 192. or 10.?

Comment: 192 But I don't think thats the problem. Its just mssql that doesn't work. MySQL does work it is possible to connect to the windows server with MySQL.

Comment: IP addresses starting with 192 are internal IP addresses. This will only work if the Windows server and the Linux webserver are in the same network. If the Linux webserver is at the server farm of the web hoster and the windows server is in your companies server farm, this will not work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16280/discussion-between-sinan-samet-and-daniel-hilgarth)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 parts to this:

FreeTDS... you will need to edit /etc/freetds.conf to include definition of the connection.

```
[CON1]
    host = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
    client charset = UTF8
    text size = 20971520

[CON2]
    host = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\PIPENAME
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
    client charset = UTF8
    text size = 20971520
```

Then, I would ignore the mssql_commands directly, and use PHP ADODB ( http://adodb.sourceforge.net/ ) to connect and run queries (especially if yoi intend to execute Stored Procs - PDO works too, but ADODB works and is reliable and consistent with SQL Server). To connect to sql server using it once you have aquired it etc:

```
    $dbMS1=ADONewConnection("mssql");
    $dbMS1->Connect('CON1','brs','TFaqAIs8');
    $dbMS1->SelectDB('TheDatabase');

    $sql = "SELECT .......";

    $rs = $dbMS1->Execute($sql);
```